# call exe using Process without absolute path

Tags: c#

I wrote a program need to call an external exe using

```
Process proc = Process.Start(filepath).
```

I specify the absolute path of the exe and it works fine. However, I need to use this program in different computers. Each time the exe has a different absolute path and I need to change the code for this part. I would like to know is there a way that I don't need to change the code? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Either you have to define a path for your application or you can search for exe in the client computer, get its path and then use that *(which will definitely take more time)*

Comment: I'm sure you can change the filepath w/o actually changing the source code.

Comment: If the exe is sure to be in a folder specified in %PATH% you could just execute the file by it's name (no path)

Comment: Could you please explain more about "If the exe is sure to be in a folder specified in %PATH% you could just execute the file by it's name (no path)" ?? Thank!

Comment: Do you know the exe's relative path to your application? Are there any environment variables that give a clue?

Comment: Yes, I can put the exe in the same folder as the application. But I don't know how to write code to specify that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If both exe-files are in the same folder, then

winforms:

```
var filepath = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath), otherexename);
Process.Start(filepath);
```

wpf:

```
var filepath = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, otherexename)
Process.Start(filepath);
```

Comment: My project is a Windows Service, can I use the first one?

Comment: You could check it for yourself (either by using msdn or trying). I don't know anything about services.

Answer (score 2):

You are asking the wrong question. Is not how to modify the API to work with your fixed requirements ("launch process w/o knowing the path", ignoring for a moment what huge security problem that is). The question you should ask is *How can I modify my code to match the API I use?*

Since starting a process works better if a full path is given (it also works if the executable  name is in %PATH%, but that is a different topic), have you app figure out the correct path and then launch the process. There are countless ways to achieve this. Probably the safest option is to use an App.Setting that points to the path. At deployment the app is properly configured with the location of the required program. there are (many) more ways to do this, it will all depend on what you're actually trying to solve, more details would be needed.

Comment: Regarding to "Use an App Setting that points to the path", do you mean I can configure the path of exe in Visual Studio(I use Visual Studio)? I actually add the exe as a reference in the project and call the exe just by its name, but it is not working.

Comment: No, I mean add an [AppSetting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.appsettings.aspx). See [How to: Add an Application Configuration File to a C# Project](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184658.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

In a windows service, you can do the following to get the directory of the currently running assembly, then to generate the right path to your exe:

```
var directory = Path.GetDirectoryName(
                  new Uri(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase).LocalPath);
var exeLocation = Path.Combine(directory,"myExe.exe");
```